# Cases created on lightning communities considered as web-to-case

Tags: community

Are cases created on lightning communities considered as web-case and bound by same limits of 5000 cases per day?

Answer (score 2):

> Are cases created on lightning communities considered as web-case and bound by same limits of 5000 cases per day?

**No.**

Creating Case from Communities is not same as created through Web-to-Case. There is no such limit defined (or documented) for number of records that can be created by a Community User. You will just need to [Enable Cases for Communities Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_cases_for_external_users.htm&type=5) for such users to be able to create Cases from Community.